# org.openid4java.message.MessageException: 0x100: Required parameter missing: openid.mode

Tags: jenkins, ldap, openid, jenkins-plugins, cas

I have jenkins configured with openID plugin for authentication. I use CAS configured with LDAP server to match the userIDs and also with openid. I am receiving an error after successful authentication when CAS is redirected back to the jenkins page after authentication.

I have attached the complete stack trace for your reference.

Regards
J Shai

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.openid4java.message.MessageException: 0x100: Required parameter missing: openid.mode
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:796)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$4.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:211)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:649)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:686)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1494)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:96)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:88)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:48)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at jenkins.security.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:117)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:93)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:164)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:46)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1474)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:499)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:533)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:949)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1011)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:668)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
at winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.openid4java.message.MessageException: 0x100: Required parameter missing: openid.mode
at org.openid4java.message.Message.validate(Message.java:187)
at org.openid4java.message.AuthSuccess.validate(AuthSuccess.java:405)
at org.openid4java.message.AuthSuccess.createAuthSuccess(AuthSuccess.java:118)
at org.openid4java.consumer.ConsumerManager.verify(ConsumerManager.java:1142)
at hudson.plugins.openid.OpenIdSession.doFinishLogin(OpenIdSession.java:111)
at hudson.plugins.openid.OpenIdSsoSecurityRealm.doFinishLogin(OpenIdSsoSecurityRealm.java:210)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:298)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:161)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:96)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:121)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
... 63 more
```

Attaching my login-webflow.xml here for reference

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Licensed to Jasig under one or more contributor license agreements. See the NOTICE file distributed with this work for 
   additional information regarding copyright ownership. Jasig licenses this file to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 
   (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at 
   the following location: http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, 
   software distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, 
   either express or implied. See the License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations under the License. -->
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd">
   <var name="credential" class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.UsernamePasswordCredential" />
   <on-start>
      <evaluate expression="initialFlowSetupAction" />
   </on-start>
   <!-- If the request contains a parameter called openid.mode and is not an association request, switch to openId. Otherwise, 
      continue normal webflow. -->
   <decision-state id="selectFirstAction">
      <if
         test="externalContext.requestParameterMap['openid.mode'] neq ''
                        &amp;&amp; externalContext.requestParameterMap['openid.mode'] neq null
                        &amp;&amp; externalContext.requestParameterMap['openid.mode'] neq 'associate'"
         then="openIdSingleSignOnAction" else="ticketGrantingTicketExistsCheck" />
   </decision-state>
   <decision-state id="ticketGrantingTicketExistsCheck">
      <if test="flowScope.ticketGrantingTicketId != null" then="hasServiceCheck" else="gatewayRequestCheck" />
   </decision-state>
   <!-- The OpenID authentication action. If authentication is successful, send the ticket granting ticker. Otherwise, redirect 
      to the login form. -->
   <action-state id="openIdSingleSignOnAction">
      <evaluate expression="openIdSingleSignOnAction" />
      <transition on="success" to="sendTicketGrantingTicket" />
      <transition on="error" to="viewLoginForm" />
      <transition on="warn" to="warn" />
   </action-state>
   <action-state id="ticketGrantingTicketCheck">
      <evaluate expression="ticketGrantingTicketCheckAction.checkValidity(flowRequestContext)" />
      <transition on="notExists" to="gatewayRequestCheck" />
      <transition on="invalid" to="terminateSession" />
      <transition on="valid" to="hasServiceCheck" />
   </action-state>
   <action-state id="terminateSession">
      <evaluate expression="terminateSessionAction.terminate(flowRequestContext)" />
      <transition to="generateLoginTicket" />
   </action-state>
   <decision-state id="gatewayRequestCheck">
      <if test="requestParameters.gateway != '' and requestParameters.gateway != null and flowScope.service != null"
         then="gatewayServicesManagementCheck" else="serviceAuthorizationCheck" />
   </decision-state>
   <decision-state id="hasServiceCheck">
      <if test="flowScope.service != null" then="renewRequestCheck" else="viewGenericLoginSuccess" />
   </decision-state>
   <decision-state id="renewRequestCheck">
      <if test="requestParameters.renew != '' and requestParameters.renew != null" then="serviceAuthorizationCheck"
         else="generateServiceTicket" />
   </decision-state>
   <!-- Do a service authorization check early without the need to login first -->
   <action-state id="serviceAuthorizationCheck">
      <evaluate expression="serviceAuthorizationCheck" />
      <transition to="generateLoginTicket" />
   </action-state>
   <!-- The "warn" action makes the determination of whether to redirect directly to the requested service or display the 
      "confirmation" page to go back to the server. -->
   <decision-state id="warn">
      <if test="flowScope.warnCookieValue" then="showWarningView" else="redirect" />
   </decision-state>
   <!-- <action-state id="startAuthenticate"> <action bean="x509Check" /> <transition on="success" to="sendTicketGrantingTicket" 
      /> <transition on="warn" to="warn" /> <transition on="error" to="generateLoginTicket" /> </action-state> -->
   <action-state id="generateLoginTicket">
      <evaluate expression="generateLoginTicketAction.generate(flowRequestContext)" />
      <transition on="generated" to="viewLoginForm" />
   </action-state>
   <view-state id="viewLoginForm" view="casLoginView" model="credential">
      <binder>
         <binding property="username" />
         <binding property="password" />
      </binder>
      <on-entry>
         <set name="viewScope.commandName" value="'credential'" />
      </on-entry>
      <transition on="submit" bind="true" validate="true" to="realSubmit">
         <evaluate expression="authenticationViaFormAction.doBind(flowRequestContext, flowScope.credential)" />
      </transition>
   </view-state>
   <action-state id="realSubmit">
      <evaluate expression="authenticationViaFormAction.submit(flowRequestContext, flowScope.credential, messageContext)" />
      <transition on="warn" to="warn" />
      <transition on="success" to="sendTicketGrantingTicket" />
      <transition on="successWithWarnings" to="showMessages" />
      <transition on="authenticationFailure" to="handleAuthenticationFailure" />
      <transition on="error" to="generateLoginTicket" />
   </action-state>
   <view-state id="showMessages" view="casLoginMessageView">
      <on-entry>
         <evaluate expression="sendTicketGrantingTicketAction" />
         <set name="requestScope.messages" value="messageContext.allMessages" />
      </on-entry>
      <transition on="proceed" to="serviceCheck" />
   </view-state>
   <action-state id="handleAuthenticationFailure">
      <evaluate expression="authenticationExceptionHandler.handle(currentEvent.attributes.error, messageContext)" />
      <transition on="AccountDisabledException" to="casAccountDisabledView" />
      <transition on="AccountLockedException" to="casAccountLockedView" />
      <transition on="CredentialExpiredException" to="casExpiredPassView" />
      <transition on="InvalidLoginLocationException" to="casBadWorkstationView" />
      <transition on="InvalidLoginTimeException" to="casBadHoursView" />
      <transition on="FailedLoginException" to="generateLoginTicket" />
      <transition on="AccountNotFoundException" to="generateLoginTicket" />
      <transition on="UNKNOWN" to="generateLoginTicket" />
   </action-state>
   <action-state id="sendTicketGrantingTicket">
      <evaluate expression="sendTicketGrantingTicketAction" />
      <transition to="serviceCheck" />
   </action-state>
   <decision-state id="serviceCheck">
      <if test="flowScope.service != null" then="generateServiceTicket" else="viewGenericLoginSuccess" />
   </decision-state>
   <action-state id="generateServiceTicket">
      <evaluate expression="generateServiceTicketAction" />
      <transition on="success" to="warn" />
      <transition on="authenticationFailure" to="handleAuthenticationFailure" />
      <transition on="error" to="generateLoginTicket" />
      <transition on="gateway" to="gatewayServicesManagementCheck" />
   </action-state>
   <action-state id="gatewayServicesManagementCheck">
      <evaluate expression="gatewayServicesManagementCheck" />
      <transition on="success" to="redirect" />
   </action-state>
   <action-state id="redirect">
      <evaluate expression="flowScope.service.getResponse(requestScope.serviceTicketId)" result-type="org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.Response"
         result="requestScope.response" />
      <transition to="postRedirectDecision" />
   </action-state>
   <decision-state id="postRedirectDecision">
      <if test="requestScope.response.responseType.name() == 'POST'" then="postView" else="redirectView" />
   </decision-state>
   <!-- the "viewGenericLogin" is the end state for when a user attempts to login without coming directly from a service. 
      They have only initialized their single-sign on session. -->
   <end-state id="viewGenericLoginSuccess" view="casLoginGenericSuccessView" />
   <!-- The "showWarningView" end state is the end state for when the user has requested privacy settings (to be "warned") 
      to be turned on. It delegates to a view defines in default_views.properties that display the "Please click here to go to 
      the service." message. -->
   <end-state id="showWarningView" view="casLoginConfirmView" />
   <!-- Password policy failure states -->
   <end-state id="abstactPasswordChangeView">
      <on-entry>
         <set name="flowScope.passwordPolicyUrl" value="passwordPolicy.passwordPolicyUrl" />
      </on-entry>
   </end-state>
   <end-state id="casExpiredPassView" view="casExpiredPassView" parent="#abstactPasswordChangeView" />
   <end-state id="casMustChangePassView" view="casMustChangePassView" parent="#abstactPasswordChangeView" />
   <end-state id="casAccountDisabledView" view="casAccountDisabledView" />
   <end-state id="casAccountLockedView" view="casAccountLockedView" />
   <end-state id="casBadHoursView" view="casBadHoursView" />
   <end-state id="casBadWorkstationView" view="casBadWorkstationView" />
   <end-state id="postView" view="postResponseView">
      <on-entry>
         <set name="requestScope.parameters" value="requestScope.response.attributes" />
         <set name="requestScope.originalUrl" value="flowScope.service.id" />
      </on-entry>
   </end-state>
   <!-- The "redirect" end state allows CAS to properly end the workflow while still redirecting the user back to the service 
      required. -->
   <end-state id="redirectView" view="externalRedirect:${requestScope.response.url}" />
   <end-state id="viewServiceErrorView" view="viewServiceErrorView" />
   <end-state id="viewServiceSsoErrorView" view="viewServiceSsoErrorView" />
   <global-transitions>
      <!-- CAS-1023 This one is simple - redirects to a login page (same as renew) when 'ssoEnabled' flag is unchecked instead 
         of showing an intermediate unauthorized view with a link to login page -->
      <transition to="viewLoginForm" on-exception="org.jasig.cas.services.UnauthorizedSsoServiceException" />
      <transition to="viewServiceErrorView" on-exception="org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.NoSuchFlowExecutionException" />
      <transition to="viewServiceErrorView" on-exception="org.jasig.cas.services.UnauthorizedServiceException" />
   </global-transitions>
</flow>
```

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved.

As it turns out the there was no URL formed to extract the parameters, as the spring configuration in the applicationContext.xml for opEnpointUrl was missing.

```
<bean id="serverManager" class="org.openid4java.server.ServerManager"
         p:oPEndpointUrl="${cas.securityContext.casProcessingFilterEntryPoint.loginUrl}"
         p:enforceRpId="false" />
```